# Python does not convert string to float after a specific row

Tags: python

i stumbeled upon a problem with python:

I'm trying to convert a row of an csv-file to a float value with the fomula

```
df= pd.read_csv(r"I:\...\file.csv", sep=";",decimal=",", encoding="latin1")
    df["cost"] = df["cost"].astype(float).
```

This works for roundabout 30.000 rows, but afterwards then i get the Error:
" ValueError: could not convert string to float: '170,48' "

I allready tried replacing the "," by a "." but this doesn't work aswell.
The same goes for trying to convert the string to a float when reading the Data (by `..., dtype={"cost":float})`

Have you got an solution for this problem?

Comment: Post a [mre] so we can help you better.

Comment: That is: show the code the tries to fix the `,`  but "doesn't work aswell".

Comment: Sure i will Post my a sample in short time

Comment: I added the sample. And im using this statement to replace the ",":   'df["cost"] = df["cost"].replace(",",".")'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks indeed like the problem occurred because there were both dots and commas within the numbers, so the `decimal=","` argument didn't work properly.

In general, if you have such a series of type `object`, where the commas indicate the decimal separator, and the dots are just for readability, you could do the following to solve the problem:

1. Convert to string.
2. Replace dots with empty characters.
3. Replace commas with dots.
4. Convert to float.

```py
df["Cost"] = df.Cost.astype(str)
df["Cost"] = df.Cost.str.replace('.', '', regex=False)
df["Cost"] = df.Cost.str.replace(',', '.', regex=False)
df["Cost"] = df.Cost.astype(float)
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay everyone i tried to change somethings in excel and it seems like the Problem has disappeared. Here is what i tried:

1. Copy the column, insert it into the editor, copy the Values from the editor and paste them back into the file
   --> Result: no result the error still occurs
2. Create a Calculated Column (value+0,01-0,01), copy and Paste the Column and insert the Values into the Column where the Error appars.
   --> no more formating error

So the Error is somehow fixed, could it really be because of the "," ?